# How can I understand OCaml user defined type?

Tags: types, ocaml

```
(* Data type definitions *)
type t =
  | True
  | False
  | If of t * t * t
  | Zero
  | Succ of t
  | Pred of t
  | IsZero of t
```

In `If of t * t * t`, why use '*' to connect, and how to understand?

Comment: You can think of the `*` as 'and'. So the `If` data constructor takes a `t` _and_ a `t` _and_ a `t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `If` constructor for your `t` type takes three arguments. In, say, Java, we would write it as a constructor like so

```
If(T a, T b, T c) { ... }
```

Now, we can think of a function which takes three arguments, conceptually, as a function which takes a tuple containing three things. A tuple is a sort of mathematical object which represents the "most general way" to have an ordered collection of a fixed size. So a tuple of three integers is the "most general way" (for some definition of "most", "general", and "way") to have three integers in a single data structure.

Now, category theorists call this "most general way" thing a product, in the same way we say the product of 3 and 5 is 15. You can read up on why we call it a product and what nice properties it has on Wikipedia if you like, but the basic idea is: tuples satisfy a lot of the "usual" mathematical properties of multiplication like commutativity, associativity, and distributivity over addition. So, to match this mathematical convention, OCaml uses `*` (the same symbol we use to multiply numbers) to indicate the "product" of types. Hence,

```
t * t * t
```

is a collection of three `t` values packed into a tuple in order. In Haskell, we would simply write this as `(T, T, T)`. If you're familiar with Typescript, we would write it as `[T, T, T]` (tuples in Typescript are just lists where we happen to know the length and types of elements in advance). Java doesn't really have an equivalent notion to this.

Comment: Be careful about comparing functions and type constructors in OCaml, as they _look_ similar but do not have the same semantics.